# How to reload a plugin using the new plugin system in Golang 1.8

Tags: go, plugins

I want to implement a plugin manager in my application with the new plugin package from Go 1.8 beta.

As the docs say (https://tip.golang.org/pkg/plugin/): "A plugin is only initialized once, and cannot be closed."

What are the implications of this?

Let's suppose I want to implement the load of plugins in runtime, and my program detects a change in a binary plugin (through md5 checking).
Do I have to restart my program to be able to load the modified and recompiled version of a plugin?
What happens when I discard every reference to the older plugin? is it garbage collected? I don't know if it's that simple so I can just discard all the references and just load the new plugin.

Comment: Like most Go docs, they are short but precise. A plugin "cannot be closed"  (i.e. unloaded), so you need to restart to ensure that only the newest version of the plugin is loaded.

Comment: @JimB so the data of the plugin keeps associated with your program in execution time until it ends execution, right?

Comment: The compiled package remains in memory, so any static data will remain. Heap allocated data is the same as any other and can be garbage collected.